# Android Room windows functions not recognized

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

I'm using API 31 with Room v2.4.2 and SQLite v3.32.2 which is supposed to support window functions. But a simple query like this

```
select *, row_number() over(order by id) from mytable
```

produces the following error at `over(`

```
<compound operator>, FROM, GROUP, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE, comma or semicolon expected, got '('
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Are you sure that SQLite's version in the device where you test the app is 3.32.2?

Comment: The error is shown in Android Studio and it won't let to build the project.

Comment: There are multiple q/a-s that this should work, but 2023 august with latest stable versions it still doesn't, this is the only Q/A that is correct, because it is without an answer.